# What part(s) can I use to connect technic liftarms at a 90 degree angle?

Tags: building, technic

[image]

Is there a way to connect the two beams in this angle and still keep the connection strong and keep the rotation the same?

Comment: By the way, if you're after strong connections, I would also suggest replacing your grey Technic pins, which are frictionless, by black ones, which will lock the beams better into place. The difference might not be huge, but it may help.

Comment: @Joubarc Thanks! A really really good tip

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You probably could use this, which looks exactly like it's the missing part of your puzzle:

[image: http://www.brickset.com/parts/?part=4296059]

You'll be interested to know that this part has intitially been proposed by the first four fans (MUPs, for [LEGO Mindstorms Users Panel](http://aboutus.lego.com/da-dk/news-room/2006/january/lego-mindstorms-users-panel/)) working on the very first NXT kit and regularly ran into the same problem as yours. A lot of Technic fans now name the part after [Steve Hassenplug](http://www.teamhassenplug.org/NXT/), as [Brian Davis started called it "hassenpin"](http://thenxtstep.blogspot.be/2006/08/robot-magazine-article-part-2.html), eventhough according to him it was more a collaborative effort. It's nice to see that LEGO does listen to the people it invites to workshops (the big wheels in the Emerald Night are another example of this).

Comment: Are we sure Steve Hassenplug didin't set up a dummy account to pose this question? :P

Comment: @gev I really can confirm i'm not him, yes :-)

Comment: I guess we'll just have to trust you... I mean, what else is there? :)

Comment: A fresh link for this part - http://www.peeron.com/inv/parts/55615. It's called "Pin connector perpendicular" in LDraw.

Answer (score 7):

[image]
[image]

If you don't have any of the 90-degree pin connectors, here is another solution using more common parts. It does add to the profile, but is sturdy.